# React - TypeError Cannot read property 'map' of undefine

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with entering usernames in the search bar. The problem is that if we enter the username and want to remove it from the search bar, an error occurs `TypeError
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in Sand Box, however, an error occurs on my computer (local) `TypeError: this.props.users.items is undefined`. This is my  code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import User from "./ItemUser";

class UsersList extends Component {
  get users() {
    return this.props.users
      ? this.props.users.items.map(user => <User key={user.id} user={user} />)
      : null;

  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.users}</div>;
  }
}

export default UsersList;
```

Comment: Please put the code here in your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that your users have an item property? Right now you're just checking to see if `this.props.users` exists, it might be helpful to add an additional check for whether those users have items like so:

`this.props.users && this.props.users.items ? ...`

I'm assuming that the error is coming from the UsersList component. If that isn't the case, let me know.

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear. @Elder, the errors you were receiving were stating that you were trying to call `map` on undefined. Since we know that you were calling the `map` function on `this.props.users.items`, we can confidently say that the `users` property exists. By checking to see if `items` we allow the `map` function to run only when `users.items` exist, otherwise we would be performing the operation regardless of whether the `items` were a property of users or not.